# AWS setup advice. EC2 + S3 - cloudfront in front?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am configuring a system that consists of two parts. An ec2 instance to run a backend, and serve a few pages, as well as an s3 bucket to serve a react app, as well as some static assets.

Obviously, I need them both to be behind ssl, and at the same domain. Which of these architectures makes more sense:

```
cloudfront (handling ssl) -|-> elastic load balancer -> ec2 instance
                           |-> s3 bucket

ec2 instance (with nginx as rev. proxy handling ssl) -|-> local server
                                                      |-> s3 bucket
```

That is - a cloudfront instance handling ssl and routing requests to either ec2 (via a load balancer) or s3, depending on the path.
Or, the ec2 instance running an nginx reverse proxy handling ssl, and routing requests to either itself, or to s3, depending on the path

Comment: I believe a better model for your backend would be `Route53` -> `Elastic-Load-Balancer` -> `EC2` because the load balancer is already capable of attaching your SSL certificate without the need of cloudfront. For the front-end section, `Route53` -> `CloudFront` -> `S3 bucket`

Comment: Ah, I hadn't considered doing them separately... Thank you!

Comment: Doing them separately gets messy due to browser cross-origin policy.  They can't be on the same hostname in that case.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Oh, what would you recommend, then?

Comment: The top one, with CloudFront in front of the stack, should give you optimal performance and reliability.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Would this still be the best solution if I wanted to put the backend on a subdomain e.g. website at www.foo.com, backend and backend.foo.com?

Comment: Sorry @Alex, I started writing up a proper answer to explain my position, but never finished it.  If you put the backend on a separate subdomain, you have more options but you also have some potential complexity.  I am a pretty strong advocate for the value proposition of CloudFront, but you would use two different CloudFront distributions if you wanted both subdomains to go through it, since they serve different, non-overlapping purposes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190774/discussion-between-alex-and-michael-sqlbot).